# View values of clusters after unsupervised classification by NDVI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, image-classification, machine-learning

I am creating unsupervised classifications of an area to detect landscape/vegetation change over time.

For each year:

- I have created an NDVI of the area based on a composite of Landsat images acquired in April and May of that year.
- I then performed an unsupervised classification (create sets of training samples > set a clusterer to kmeans with 5 clusters > instantiate a clusterer for each NDVI > create and display classes)

I would like to see how the NDVI values were portioned into different classes (ex: Class 1 = 0.0 - 0.2, Class 2 = 0.2 - 0.45, etc.) Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

To figure out what K-Means did, you (re)cluster the training data and then compute the mean of each of those clusters with reduceColumns and a grouped reducer.  If you only have 1 covariate, then the breaks will be 1/2 way between the mean of each pair of neighbours.